# Does removing some drop ceiling panels make plug-in lights OK?

Tags: code-compliance

I am uplighting a room with a drop ceiling.  Cheap 4' fluorescent shop lights are hung below the drop ceiling, with their cords disappearing into a corner of a drop ceiling panel. Real hack job.  Above the drop ceiling, they plug into the usual NEMA 5-15 sockets.  USA/NEC 2014.  I hear NEC prohibits this, but it would be OK if the drop ceiling grid were present but the panels were not (which apparently is a style now).

Weirdly, the drop ceiling panels are 2x5’.  They can comfortably frame a 4' fixture.

So here's my idea.  Hang the fixtures so they are about 3" above the plane of the drop ceiling, and remove the drop ceiling panels altogether where the lights are.  They would remain everywhere else.  The receptacles may be above areas where there are still panels.

Would this satisfy the NEC rules about flexible cords / cord-and-plug-connected luminaires in drop ceilings?